# How to filter MongoDB documents based on one specific document's array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like this:

```js
{
  _id: "blabla",
  userName: "blablabla",
  ..
  interactedUsers: [
    "blabla2"
    "some other user's id",
    "some other user's id",
  ]
},
{
  _id: "blabla2",
  userName: "blablabla2",
  ..
  interactedUsers: [
    "some other user's id",
    "some other user's id",
  ]
},
```

Now if i am the user with `"_id: "blabla"` i want to fetch all users except `"blabla2"` because its in my `"interactedUsers"` array. How can i do that? I tried so many aggregation combinations but couldn't really get the wanted result.

Comment: So, you want to retrieve all `"_id"` except those that appear in `"interactedUsers"` of the document with `"_id": "blabla"`?  Do you also want to exclude `"blabla"`?  BTW, it's better if you show the queries you tried and explain why the output is not what you want.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes i want to exclude the "blabla" user if possible. I am going to add some queries to the post

Comment: @rickhg12hs I didn't save my previous queries and tried to solve the problem but couldn't really get anywhere so i can't add any queries to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably don't want to use `$facet` as it will merge all your collection into one big document, another option is to use `$lookup`.

This allows you to add the "ignored" document to all other documents and then remove from the answer the ones that contain it. The advantage here is that all your documents are kept separated along the process:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {"ignore": "blabla" }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "ignore",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "ignore"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {ignore: {$arrayElemAt: ["$ignore", 0]}}
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {$not: {$in: ["$_id", "$ignore.interactedUsers"]}}
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "ignore"
  },
  {
    $match: {$expr: {$ne: ["$_id", "blabla"]}}
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_-jr_v0bcuz)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to return all `"_id"` in the collection not in `"interactedUsers"`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": "blabla0" } },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": { "notIds": { "$setUnion": [ [ "$_id" ], "$interactedUsers" ] } },
      "pipeline": [
        { "$match": { "$expr": { "$not": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$notIds" ] } } } },
        { "$project": { "_id": 1 } }
      ],
      "as": "strangers"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "strangers": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$strangers",
          "in": "$$this._id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZSNYi0h8KxS).